# Remove margin reserved for dock when dock is hidden

Tags: macos, dock

I upgraded to Sierra. Previously, when I had the dock hidden, windows could be resized to take up almost all of the screen; a 4 pixel margin was reserved for the dock. Now, when I have the dock hidden, the margin is no longer just 4 pixels: the margin is the size as the dock. I hid the dock to make extra space for my windows, but it seems like that benefit of hiding the dock is lost. Is there a way to revert to the previous behavior?

Comment: Just have to check since I do not have this problem - what version of Sierra are you running ( > About This Mac) and have you rebooted after hiding the dock? It's working fine for me on 10.12.5

Comment: @Jackson1442 10.12.5

Comment: Interesting. And you have restarted?

Comment: @Jackson1442 I'll try that. A restart hadn't previously been necessary.

Comment: @Jackson1442 Restarting fixed it. Feel free to submit your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reboot.

Sometimes, settings don't come into effect until you reboot your device, especially if it's a system-wide preference. Rebooting tends to solve most System Preferences-related issues.

Also, System Preferences may not tell you to reboot your device, but if something isn't working, restarting should solve your issue.

**If Dock settings do not work correctly, a reboot should solve your problem.**